# Why no Output in PHP OOP program?

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php

class TrimPHP_Strings {    
    public $str;

    public function Apply() {    
            return $this->str;
    }

    function __constructor($str) {    
        $this->str = $str;
    }

}

function Strings($str) {
    $obj = new TrimPHP_Strings($str);
    return $obj;
}
?>
<?php    
echo Strings("My String")->Apply();
?>
```

I can not understand why the above code doesn't work? I expect it to output `My String` but it simply outputs a blank page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper name for the constructor is `__construct`, not `__constructor`

Comment: Argh... Always fell like an idiot when I make such stupid mistakes. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I know the feeling all too well Shashank ;-)